# How to sort a Combobox programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

In my winforms application, I was looking for a way to add an item (Bitmap object) at the beginning of comboBox after sorting all other items.

I was expecting to see method `Sort()` for comboBoxes but all what I can find as solution was to turn on/off `Sorted` feature:

```
// add all items to mycomboBox
mycomboBox.Sorted = true;
mycomboBox.Sorted = false;
mycomboBox.Insert(0, myItem);
```

Is there a better option to insert a new item at position 0 of sorted combobox?

Note: I'm using Net Framework 4.0

Comment: You sort the datasource of the combobox

Comment: If you're using a sorted combobox how is that you're putting an element in an arbitrary position?

Comment: I want to add a default option to mycomboBox, so it is better to put it at the top of sorted list

Comment: @Steve mycomboBox.DataSource is null. I'm adding items to mycomboBox.items manually

Comment: Why don't you add them in the correct order in the first place? How are you generating your items?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have both sorting and manual placement.

I would recommend simply adding the items to the combobox pre-sorted, assuming you can add them all at once.

```
myComboBox.Items.Add(myList.OrderBy(r => r).ToArray());
```

Comment: I believe this needs to be "Items.AddRange" instead of "Items.Add" if the param is an array.